# React.js: Get value from an icon component works inconsistently

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A table component renders trash icons that I would like to bind to mapped `couponId`'s to post delete requests through:

```
  <FaTrashAlt
    value={record.couponId}
    onClick={e => {
      console.log(e.target.getAttribute('value'), `=====e.target.getAttribute('value')=====`);
    }}
  />
```

The first row of the table shows the `couponId`, seen below. Clicking the above does work maybe 10% of the time, but most of the time it returns null:

[image: Image of rendering and console values]

Clicking the same delete icon quickly lowers the chance of the value logging so I think there is some sort of async issue in play here.

What is a more reliable way to bind a value to an icon or image and pass it to an onClick handler?

Comment: Why not just do `onClick={e => handleOnClick(record.couponId)}`?

Comment: Works, thanks. I guess my mind was trained around input fields but for icons this will do nicely